# Autofilter: Copy & paste. How to Offset when inserting copied data?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to offset the data I'm copying, so the new data doesn't erase the old data.

I tried to different methods with offset. But I'm clearly doing something wrong

```
Dim lastrow As Long: lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim lastrow2 As Long: lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "h").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Test")
    .AutoFilterMode = False
    .Range("A1:C" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:="=TEST Sheet", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .Range("A1:C" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="=New"
    .Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("H26").Offset(lastrow2, 0)
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

So basically all the copied data goes into to Row H, but the list should keep getting larger.

Comment: Just a typo. You are defining `lastrow` twice but not `lastrow2`.

Comment: Other than it being a typo you can also forget about the offset and just write .Range("H" & 26 + lastrow2)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sometimes you can't see the answer which is just in front of you :)